# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf = "Whitelabel Error Page" when trying to render index.html

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to do simple Spring MVC Library

Do You have any idea why I have problem with View, when i use homepage method in my controller it should show me index.html but i only get **Whitelabel Error Page** all the time, and i dont know why:/

My structure:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5c35.png

My controller:

```
package controller;


import model.Book;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import service.BookService;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.List;


@Controller
public class LiberianController{

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String homepage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/allBooks")
    public ModelAndView allBooks(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        List<Book> books = bookService.getAllBooks();
        modelAndView.addObject("listBooks", books);
        modelAndView.setViewName("allBooks");

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/addBook")
    public ModelAndView newBook(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        Book book = new Book();
        modelAndView.addObject("book", book);
        modelAndView.setViewName("addBook");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "updateBook")
    public ModelAndView updateBook(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        long id = Long.parseLong(httpServletRequest.getParameter("id"));
        Book book = bookService.getBook(id);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("addBook");
        modelAndView.addObject("book", book);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveBook",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveBook(@ModelAttribute Book book) {

        if (book.getId() == 0) {
            bookService.addBook(book);

        } else {
            bookService.updateBook(book.getId(), book);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/allBooks");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteBook")
    public ModelAndView deleteBook(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        long id = Long.parseLong(httpServletRequest.getParameter("id"));
        bookService.deleteBook(id);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/allBooks");
    }





}
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MyLibrary</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

aplication.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things wrong with your demo project.

#### 1. Incorrect package structure

You put your `Runner` class to a default package. It not a good idea, because in this case Spring Boot is not able to set a default package for component scanning. When you run your application you should see something like:

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.
```

**Solution**: move all your classes to common package.

#### 2. `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` is missing

In your `pom.xml` file add following dependency to make Thymeleaf templates working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then remove following dependency that is present in your `pom.xml`:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

#### 3. `spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5` requires additional dependency

When you run your app and you open http://localhost:8080 you will see following exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot perform conversion to XML from legacy HTML: The nekoHTML library is not in classpath. nekoHTML 1.9.15 or newer is required for processing templates in "LEGACYHTML5" mode [http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net]. Maven spec: "net.sourceforge.nekohtml::nekohtml::1.9.15". IMPORTANT: DO NOT use versions of nekoHTML older than 1.9.15.
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.html.AbstractHtmlTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractHtmlTemplateParser.java:90) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
```

This is because you have specified:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

and you haven't add `nekoHTML` library to the classpath.

**Solution**: add following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.22</version>
</dependency>
```

After applying all these steps you will see "Hello" on your app's home page. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I second the solution of using the right packages, I had my error in the same place.

When I was using this :

```xml
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.X.X</version>
      </dependency>
```

The view refuses to display itself and fails silently.

But on the other hand, if we mention no version and let springboot handle dependency version it all works out well, so the working dependency would be :

```xml
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).